# RunaWFE файл main_layout.jsp не редактируется

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlet

Пытаюсь добавить пункт меню в веб интерфейсе RunaWFE, но безрезультатно. Не отображаются изменения, даже обычный текст в HTML тегах вроде

```html
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

не отображается, все остаётся без изменений. Редактирую этот файл  https://github.com/processtech/runawfe-free-server/blob/master/wfe-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/af/main_layout.jsp#L106.

Answer (score 0):

Решил. Нужно пересобирать весь проект и копировать на сервер новый runawfe.ear